# How to configure a Confluent Kafka Connect local S3 sink

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, fakes3

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 12
      KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: gzip
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9091
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8083
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: __connect-config
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: __connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: __connect-status
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: ' /usr/share/java/'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:  "1234"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "1234"
    ports:
      - 8083:8083

  s3:
    image: vladnev/fake-s3
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:  "1234"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "1234"
```

And the configuration to create the S3 connector:

```
{
  "name": "s3-sink",
  "config": {

    "_comment": "The S3 sink connector class",
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",

    "_comment": "The total number of Connect tasks to spawn (with implicit upper limit the number of topic-partitions)",
    "tasks.max":"1",

    "_comment": "Which topics to export to S3",
    "topics":"__connect-config",

    "_comment": "The S3 bucket that will be used by this connector instance",
    "s3.bucket.name":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",

    "_comment": "The AWS region where the S3 bucket is located",
    "s3.region":"us-west-2",

    "_comment": "The size in bytes of a single part in a multipart upload. The last part is of s3.part.size bytes or less. This property does not affect the total size of an S3 object uploaded by the S3 connector",
    "s3.part.size":"5242880",

    "_comment": "The maximum number of Kafka records contained in a single S3 object. Here a high value to allow for time-based partition to take precedence",
    "flush.size":"100000",

    "_comment": "Kafka Connect converter used to deserialize keys (unused in this example)",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",

    "_comment": "Kafka Connect converter used to deserialize values",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",

    "_comment": "The type of storage for this storage cloud connector",
    "storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",

    "_comment": "The storage format of the objects uploaded to S3",
    "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",

    "_comment": "Schema compatibility mode between records with schemas (Useful when used with schema-based converters. Unused in this example, listed for completeness)",
    "schema.compatibility":"NONE",

    "_comment": "The class used to partition records in objects to S3. Here, partitioning based on time is used.",
    "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",

    "_comment": "The locale used by the time-based partitioner to encode the date string",
    "locale":"en",

    "_comment": "Setting the timezone of the timestamps is also required by the time-based partitioner",
    "timezone":"UTC",

    "_comment": "The date-based part of the S3 object key",
    "path.format":"'date'=YYYY-MM-dd/'hour'=HH",

    "_comment": "The duration that aligns with the path format defined above",
    "partition.duration.ms":"3600000",

    "_comment": "The interval between timestamps that is sufficient to upload a new object to S3. Here a small interval of 1min for better visualization during the demo",
    "rotate.interval.ms":"60000",

    "_comment": "The class to use to derive the timestamp for each record. Here Kafka record timestamps are used",
    "timestamp.extractor":"Record"
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to test this setup against a real S3 bucket yet, so maybe it's not quite right, and I'm probably going to need to configure something else if I wanted to test it against AWS. But for now, only locally, what should I change so that it sends the messages to the fake s3 container? I guess I need to modify the `s3.bucket.name` and `s3.region` properties, but I don't know how. Perhaps it is not possible?

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: I've added the `fakes3` tag as this sounds like a question on how to use that specific tool (https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3).

Comment: Thanks @RobinMoffatt

Answer (score 0):

You should override `store.url` for the connector configs.
Here is an example https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/372#issuecomment-1152743782 where `"store.url": "http://localstack:4566"` is a path to your local s3 server